# Как вывести внутренний элемент за пределы блока?

Tags: javascript, html, css

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

как я могу вывести блок-ц за пределы родительского кол-9 и расположить его во всю ширину. в блоке-а меню, которое при клике меняет контент, потому контент должен желательо распологаться в кол-9.

Comment: Block-c можно вынести в отдельную строчку `.row`.

Comment: верстку покажите, а не картинку

Answer (score 0):

Используйте отрицательный `margin`

```css
.sidebar {
  border-right: 1px solid #eaeaea;
}
.block {
  height: 150px;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}
.block-a {
  background-color: yellow;
}
.block-b {
  background-color: gray;
}
.block-c {
  background-color: lightcoral;
  margin-left: -150px;
  
}
```

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-3 col-md-3 sidebar">
      <div class="block block-a"><h1>BLOCK A</h1></div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-9 col-md-9">
      <div class="block block-b"><h1>BLOCK B</h1></div>
      <div class="block block-c"><h1>BLOCK C</h1></div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```